# Altering LAN Settings from a batch file and/or C#?

Tags: c#, proxy, batch-file

I'm not sure how to describe this without an image, so attached is a quick snip from what I want to do in a batch file (Windows 7 Enterprise 32 bit)

[image: LAN Proxy]

In Internet Options, under the Connections tab, there's a LAN settings button (marked in red), that opens the displayed dialog from the image. I already have the address and port I want, all I want is a way to check or uncheck the marked checkbox from a batch file. I would also accept an answer for how to do it in C#.

EDIT:

For other people who stumble across this question, this question is just for me being a power user. If you have a product that needs to change Proxy server settings, don't assume the settings are correct, use PostMan's second registry entry to properly set the proxy first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can do this using the command reg.

it's stored in `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\`

so you can use the following command in a batch file:

```
reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\\" /v "ProxyEnable" /T REG_DWORD /d 1
```

This will set the `ProxyEnable` to 1 (Enabled)

and

```
reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\\" /v "ProxyServer" /T REG_SZ /d "192.168.1.1:8080
```

To set the proxy to `192.169.1.1:8080`

Take note of the extra slash at the end of Internet Settings, without it the slash cancels the "

Also, You can add `/f` to force the over writing of the old value, currently it will ask to confirm overriding.

Comment: Thank you @PostMan. Do you know how to set or unset 'Automatically Detect Settings' checkbox, too?

Comment: @GokcenG create a String field named 'AutoConfigURL' with your automatic config url, and this will tick the checkbox and populate the text box with the contents of this registry entry. Create the field in the same location as above (HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\)

Comment: Hi @PostMan. I think I've stated my question wrong. I wonder the check box next to the 'Automatically Detect Settings' not 'Use automatic configuration script'.

Comment: @GokcenG I believe (based on very small testing) that the checkbox is driven from the AutoConfigURL field, so if you remove it then the checkbox won't be checked.

Comment: I am really interested in unchecking that checkbox too, since if it is checked it does not go online (it does not prompt me the password for the proxy connection). Any help?

Comment: solid! thanks! but, there's any doc files where i can know how did u get that url? and those field names?

Answer (score 1):

You could use Powershell for playing with proxy settings from a batch file or command line, one example in this blog entry http://devpinoy.org/blogs/velocity/archive/2007/06/23/setting-proxy-settings-in-ie-using-powershell.aspx